# A macro that passes each word of its argument to another macro as an argument?

Tags: macros

I'd like a command that works like this:

```
\dothings{Takes several words as argument}
```

and have this expand to:

```
\@dothings{Takes} \@dothings{several} \@dothings{words}...
```

I know how to define a simple macro that takes everything up to the next space, but I don't know how to use that to apply it to *each* word in a sentence. Is there a simple way to do this?

I'm also curious about taking the next *letter* as an argument, but I guess that's maybe a separate question...

Comment: I just found this related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11595/iterate-over-space-separated-list

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\dothings#1{\color{blue}\expandafter\dothings@i#1 \@nil}
\def\dothings@i#1 #2\@nil{%
  \color{.!80}#1
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\dothings@i#2\@nil\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\dothings{Takes several words as argument}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this needs an extra set of `{}` to keep the color change local to `\donothing`. So the first `\def` should be `\def\dothings#1{{\color{blue}\expandafter\dothings@i#1 \@nil}}`

Comment: The `\expandafter` is useless?

Comment: @Leo Liu: I guess that Herbert wants to also cover the case where the sentence is given within a macro.

Answer (score 15):

LaTeX3 now provides

`\seq_set_split:Nnn`*`<seq var>`*`{`*`<delimiter>`*`} {`*`<argument>`*`}`

which splits the *`<argument>`* at each occurrence of *`<delimiter>`* (and strips spaces from both ends of each argument), and puts the result in the *`<seq var>`* (the list data structure in LaTeX3). Once you have that sequence, you can map a given function on all its items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_foo_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\dothings}{m}
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_foo_seq {~} {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_foo_seq { \fbox{##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\dothings{Takes several words as argument}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Actually you can do it faster with xparse's *argument processors* (here `\SplitList`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\dothings}
  { > { \SplitList { ~ } } m }
  { \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} { \fbox{##1} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\dothings{Takes several words as argument}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's neat! I like that!

Comment: When this goes onto CTAN, could you update this answer to reflect that?

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for the reminder, it is now on CTAN.

Answer (score 9):

Herbert has shown how to seperate words by spaces. Here is a very similar solution which prevent deep `\ifx ... \fi` nesting (Deep nesting may produce errors when many words is used):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

\def\wordsloop#1{\wordsloopiter#1 \nil}
\def\wordsloopiter#1 #2\nil{%
  \do{#1} %
  \ifx&#2&% #2 is empty, then & equeals &
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    \def\next{\wordsloopiter#2\nil}% iterate
  \fi
  \next}

\def\do#1{(#1)}
\wordsloop{This is a sentence.}
% we have: (This) (is) (a) (sentence.)

\end{document}
```

However, it is still very slow if you use many words in the argument.

---

Loop on tokens can be obtained by similar approch, if you remove the spaces after `#1` in the definitions above. But it can be easier:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

\def\tokensloop#1{\tokensloopiter#1\nil}
\def\tokensloopiter#1{%
  \ifx\nil#1\else\do{#1}\expandafter\tokensloopiter\fi}

\def\do#1{(#1)}
\tokensloop{aa  bb}
% we have (a)(a)(b)(b)

\end{document}
```

You can also use `\toksloop` command from `etextools` package directly.

*Note that spaces are ignored.*

---

For spaces, catcode or other tricks may be used to read the characters verbatimly. That is more complex.

For example, we can use `\obeyspaces` to change the catcode of spaces:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

\def\charsloop{\begingroup\obeyspaces\charsloophelper}
\def\charsloophelper#1{\charsloopiter#1\nil\endgroup}
\def\charsloopiter#1{%
  \ifx\nil#1\else\do{#1}\expandafter\charsloopiter\fi}

\def\do#1{(#1)}
\charsloop{aa  bb}
% we have (a)(a)( )( )(b)(b)

\end{document}
```

(Newlines are still ignored with `\obeyspaces` only.)

Comment: Is it simple to modify this to separate based on `&`. I am still searching for a more general solution to [macro to allow for alignment points within its argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14827/macro-to-allow-for-alignment-points-within-its-argument)

Answer (score 3):

ConTeXt provides a macro `\processisolatedwords` that does exactly that. For example, to draw a frame around each word, you can use

```
\processisolatedwords {\input ward \relax} \inframed
```

In MkIV, this macro is implemented in lua using the following funcction:

```
local function applytowords(list,what,nested)
    local doaction = context[what or "ruledhbox"]
    local noaction = context
    local current  = checkedlist(list)
    local start
    while current do
        local id = current.id
        if id == glue_code then
            if start then
                doaction(copynodelist(start,current))
                start = nil
            end
            noaction(copynode(current))
        elseif nested and (id == hlist_code or id == vlist_code) then
            context.hbox()
            context.bgroup()
            applytowords(current.list,what,nested)
            context.egroup()
        elseif not start then
            start = current
        end
        current = current.next
    end
    if start then
        doaction(copynodelist(start))
    end
end
```

See also:

- `\applytowords`
- `\processwords` and `\applytosplitstringword`