# How to exclude text portions by simply setting a variable or option?

Tags: macros, text-manipulation

I'm writing a document where some text portions are confidential and would therefore like to create an environment (e.g. `confidential`) which I can then exclude from the PDF by simply setting a variable or option.

Is there any way of doing this in LaTeX, or better yet, is there a package for this?

Comment: If you want to simply remove/skip such environments then Joseph's solution is the way to go. If you want to replace the text with something else, e.g. empty space, than have a look at [Phantom and line break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16003/phantom-and-line-break), which could be modified to not even draw the underlining.

Comment: Here are some attempts as solving this for inline or paragraph text that maintains the paragraph typesetting (hyphenation at line breaks - not supported by `\phantom`): [Censor text spanning multiple lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26283/5764). The [`soul` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) provided a good solution to tapping into the line breaking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want the [comment](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) package. This provides the `\includecomment` and `\excludecomment` macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{confidential}
\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{confidential}
Some secret text
\end{confidential}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I ran into a problem where I got a lot of errors about too many `}`s or missing `\endgroup`s and it took a while to find out how to fix it: [How to fix issues with closing the commented out environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29060/newenvironment-issues-with-environment-comment#comment72226_29073)

Comment: Note that this way it's not possible to have space before the `\end{confidential}` line, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624081/including-an-optional-answer-in-an-exam-paper/624212#624212

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `newcommand` and `renewcommand` in conjunction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\confidential}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\condidential}[1]{} %Comment out this whole line to surpress exclusion.
\begin{document}
    His name was \confidential{Frank}.
\end{document}
```

One advantage with this method is that you easily can style the text in different ways, and you can put a standard message to appear whenever something is excluded.

For example:

```
\newcommand{\confidential}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

makes all the included, confidential information appear in **bold**.

Further,

```
\renewcommand{\condidential}[1]{\textbf{CONFIDENTIAL}}
```

makes all the confidential information, when excluded, replaced with a placeholder which says: **CONFIDENTIAL**.

You can also easily set up different environments for different needs. For example, if you want to have different levels of confidentiality, you can have a `\superConfidential` environment in addition to the `\confidential` environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the [comment](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment) package (as suggested by [Joseph Wright's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28098/34574)) giving you trouble when using its `comment` environment inside some complex structures like footnotes, use the [version](https://ctan.org/pkg/version) package which appears to be a drop-in replacement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{version}
\excludeversion{confidential}
\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{confidential}
Some secret text
\end{confidential}

\end{document}
```

It also works inside a footnote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{version}
\excludeversion{confidential}
\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{confidential}
Some secret text
\end{confidential}

\footnote{A footnote.
\begin{confidential}
\item Some secret text
\end{confidential}
}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to muk.li for sharing this in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275523/34574).

Comment: Notice that description of `version` on CTAN warns _"Although the command syntax is very similar to that of `comment`, comment.sty is to be preferred to version.sty for documents where significant chunks of text may be excluded"_. I don't know the rationale though...