# Colored box in new environment

Tags: color, boxes, minipage, books

I have a problem, I'm fairly new to LaTeX but I think I got the basics.

My problem is that wants to create a environment that can create a minipage with a background color and some text in it.

I can make this by doing it by hand, but I have a lot of boxes, and to write mostly the same over and over again is to my a bit redundant.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}   % Book settings + layout

\usepackage{xcolor}         % Extended colors
\usepackage{color}         % Color extended names

%DEFINE ENVIRONMENT BLOCK
% Riddle
\newenvironment{colbox}[3]{        % Riddle environment
  \begin{center}                   % Centering minipage
    \colorbox[HTML]{#1} {          % Set's the color of minipage
      \begin{minipage}[b]{380px}   % Starts minipage
   \textbf{#2}\\ \textit{#3}       % Set's title and starts italic for text
  \end{minipage}}                  % End minipage
}{\end{center}}                    % End Riddle environment


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \colorbox[HTML]{F8E0E0}{
     \begin{minipage}[c]{380px}
      \textbf{Riddle: }\\ \textit{some text here}
     \end{minipage}}
\end{center}

Some other text

\begin{colbox}{F8E0E0}{Riddle:}
  some text here
\end{colbox}

Some more text

\begin{colbox}{F8E0E0}{Riddle:}
  {some text here}
\end{colbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of the problem]

As I can see it, the problem is that in my environment `colorbox` is not ended by the end parameter, and I need to move `\end{minipage}` the same place, but I can't move it before the `\end{colorbox}` is moved, is there a way to do this right?

```
%DEFINE ENVIRONMENT BLOCK
% Riddle
\newenvironment{colbox}[3]{        % Riddle environment
  \begin{center}                   % Centering minipage
    \colorbox[HTML]{#1} {          % Set's the color of minipage
      \begin{minipage}[b]{380px}   % Starts minipage
   \textbf{#2}\\ \textit{#3}       % Set's title and starts italic for text
  \end{minipage} }                 % End minipage
}{\end{center}}
```

I can "fix" the out-of-box problem by putting `{}` on the text like this

```
\begin{colbox}{F8E0E0}{Riddle:}
  {some text here}
\end{colbox}
```

But that's not really what I want.

If it's possible I would like to keep everything in what's default in LaTeX cause I'm not the only one maintaining this document and special packages is not well liked,

Comment: Just a comment on the use of `xcolor` + `color` packages: `xcolor` already has options to get more names, for example `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}` makes a lot of names available. See the `xcolor` manual.

Comment: The question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29060/newenvironment-issues seems to be very similar, but has an extra comment-it-out part.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The box has to be collected before typesetting it with a colored background:

```
\newsavebox{\selvestebox}
\newenvironment{colbox}[1]
  {\newcommand\colboxcolor{#1}%
   \begin{lrbox}{\selvestebox}%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \begin{center}
   \colorbox[HTML]{\colboxcolor}{\usebox{\selvestebox}}
   \end{center}}
```

The `lrbox` environment is very useful for this kind of business.

You don't have to guess the width (and `px` is not the unit I would use); just remember that a padding of `\fboxsep` is added to the contents of `\colorbox`.

Now

```
\begin{colbox}{F8E0E0}
\textbf{Riddle: }\\ \textit{some text here}
\end{colbox}
```

will work. Notice how one can carry the argument to the "end part" of the environment, this is a standard technique.

Comment: Well clarified answer!

Comment: Isn't that basically the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29060/newenvironment-issues/29061#29061. Maybe the questions should be merged.

Comment: @MartinScharrer They are almost the same indeed.

Comment: @egreg: Anyway, I decided that both questions only overlap but aren't complete duplicates. I now also added an answer using `adjustbox`.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify the creation of such environments you can use a packages like [`framed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) or [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ).

Example with `framed` (this allows page breaks):

```
\newenvironment{colbox}{%
   \def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{colboxcolor}}%
   \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}
 {\endMakeFramed}
```

and e.g.

```
\definecolor{colboxcolor}{HTML}{F8E0E0}
```

Then use:

```
\begin{colbox}
Text
\end{colbox}
```

Example with package `environ` (no page break):

```
\NewEnviron{colbox}[1][\linewidth]{%
  \colorbox{\colboxcolor}{%
     \begin{minipage}{#1}
       \BODY
     \end{minipage}%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in for very related question [\newenvironment issues with environment comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29060/newenvironment-issues/29073#29073) such boxes can be done quite easily with the `adjustbox` package. The technical solution is basically the same as in egreg's answer but with a much nicer and more flexible user interface.
You can adjust the margin with the `margin` key and set the background color with `bgcolor` which uses similar code like `\colorbox`. You need to load `xcolor` by yourself for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{colbox}[2]{%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[b]{380px},margin=1ex,bgcolor=#1,env=center}% or use `bgcolor={HTML}{#1}` if you want to force HTML colors
        \textbf{#2}\\
}{%
    \end{adjustbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{colbox}{green}{Riddle me this, Batman:}
    What is ....
\end{colbox}

\begin{colbox}{{HTML}{F8E0E0}}{Riddle 2:}
    What is ....
\end{colbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all, for all your answers...

I looked at all of them, and have decided that the first solution is the right one for me.

The reasoning for this is: It's a very simple solution and it gets the job done, and as stated in the first post I'm not the only one maintaining this document, so simplicity is a good thing...

Again thanks for you help, and have a nice day to all

**My Final Solution**

If somebody in the future wants to see the answer I ended up with, have I supplied my final code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}   % Book settings + layout

\usepackage{xcolor}         % Extended colors
\usepackage{color}         % Color extended names

%DEFINE ENVIRONMENT BLOCK
% Riddle
\newsavebox{\riddlebox}
\newenvironment{colboxTre}[1]
{\newcommand\colboxcolor{#1}%
\begin{lrbox}{\riddlebox}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep\relax} \textbf{Riddle:} \\ \itshape }
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\begin{center}
  \colorbox[HTML]{\colboxcolor}{\usebox{\riddlebox}}
\end{center}}


\begin{document}

\begin{colboxTre}{F8E0E0}
  some text here
\end{colboxTre}

Some more text

\end{document}
```

[image: My Final Solution]