# Defining a new environment/command to encapsulate a colorbox

Tags: tables, macros, environments, colorbox

I have the following working MWE file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\centering%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\toprule%
Column 1 & Column 2\tabularnewline% Unchanging column headers
\midrule%
One-one & One-two\tabularnewline% Changing content line one
Two-one & Two-two\tabularnewline% Changing content line two
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would like to extract the static portions of this setup into either a new environment or a new command so that only the changing content lines will be passed to the new environment, say `mytable`, as

```
\begin{mytable}
One-one & One-two\tabularnewline% Changing content line one
Two-one & Two-two\tabularnewline% Changing content line two
\end{mytable}
```

or new command, say `\mytable`, as

```
\mytable{%
One-one & One-two\tabularnewline% Changing content line one
Two-one & Two-two\tabularnewline% Changing content line two
}
```

The `\colorbox` seems to throw a spanner in the works for this effort. How might I surmount this problem, please?

**EDIT**

In answer to @David Carlisle's query, here is the command version of what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%
\newcommand{\mycontents}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\centering%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\toprule%
Column 1 & Column 2\tabularnewline% Column headers
\midrule%
#1 % mind no braces {} around #1; that caused the error reported below
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular}}} % table environment removed as suggested by @egreg
%
\begin{document}

\mycontents{One-one & One-two\tabularnewline%
Two-one & Two-two\tabularnewline}

\end{document}
```

The error was:

````
```! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.25 Two-one & Two-two\tabularnewline}
                                    
?```
````

Comment: Duplicate of [color - Colored box in new environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29769/colored-box-in-new-environment).

Comment: it requires  bit of care to use any macro on an environment body but your second form as an argument would just be a simple `\newcommand`  replacing `One-...line two` by `#1`. what error did you get?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I get this error: ```! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.25 Two-one & Two-two\tabularnewline}
                                    
?```

I have appended my question above with the command version just in case it has an obvious error.

Comment: why did you add `{}` ? They were not in your original code, `#1` not `{#1}` That is why you should always put full code in the question, we would have had no clue about the error in code until you show it

Comment: Thanks, @ David Carlisle. I was not aware that `{}` pairs could lead to such problems in LaTeX. I think that adding gratuitous brace pairs is a carry over from `bash` where the defensive programming recommendation is to add them rather than leave them out. I can confirm that it works correctly now, And the command version is straightforward as you have alluded to.

Comment: I have commented and corrected the example above so that it works, and may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `table`: when there's no caption, the `table` environment doesn't really make sense, because if the table floats there's no way to identify it.

Instead of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in the code below you can use `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` if you want all these tables to be centered. But maybe you want to have two of them side-by-side and it would be impossible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\mytable}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \colorbox{lightgray}{%
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    \toprule
    Column 1 & Column 2 \\
    \midrule
    #1
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\mytable{
  One-one & One-two \\
  Two-one & Two-two \\
}

\end{document}
```

Note that you either must always add `\\` at the end or never, if you place the trailing `\\` before `\bottomrule`.

[image]

Can the condition be relieved? Yes, but with some further work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytableheaders}{}{Column 1 & Column 2}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytable}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \colorbox{lightgray}
   {
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    \toprule
    \mytableheaders \\
    \midrule
    \chandra_mytable_body:n { #1 }
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \group_end:
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \chandra_mytable_body:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { (\c{\\} | \c{tabularnewline})\s* \Z } { #1 }
   {% there was a trailing \\
    #1
   }
   {% no trailing \\
    #1 \\
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mytable{
  One-one & One-two \\
  Two-one & Two-two \\
}

\bigskip

\mytable{
  One-one & One-two \tabularnewline
  Two-one & Two-two \tabularnewline
}

\bigskip

\mytable{
  One-one & One-two \\
  Two-one & Two-two
}

\bigskip

\mytable{
  One-one & One-two \tabularnewline
  Two-one & Two-two
}

\end{document}
```

The argument is checked for a trailing `\\` or `\tabularnewline` followed by spaces (that may be inserted by the endline after `\\`). If it's absent, one is added.

[image]

Comment: I agree that `table` should not be part of the command. In your modified examples, for the third example, should not the second line be missing a ``\\``? Where can I learn to understand the augmented experimental syntax you have used?

Comment: @chandra Yes, there was an unwanted ``\\``. Look for `\ExplSyntaxOn` on the site and you’ll find many examples to study.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I have found this discussion to be a good starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108696/what-do-explsyntaxon-and-explsyntaxoff-do/108703#108703