# Comment package not working

Tags: comments

I have added the package `\usepackage{comment}` in my .tex file. But when I am adding `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` it is not commenting the text I want to comment. What to do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `comment` manual says: "The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it." Do you place your `comment` environment like this?

Comment: @Ignasi You're right!

Comment: There are alternatives without the starting spaces limitation – `verbatim` package or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28096/how-to-exclude-text-portions-by-simply-setting-a-variable-or-option/325928#325928

Answer (score 13):

I have attempted to reproduce this problem, and have only been able to come up with only **one** way to do that. And that is to have the following after the `comment` package is included:

```
\renewenvironment{comment}{}{}
```

So, if you un-comment this line the MWE below, you get the behavior you describe. With it commented, the text in red and blue does NOT show up in the output.  So, check your preamble add see if there is something else that is redefining the behavior of the `comment` environment.

If you have another way of reproducing this behaviour, please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

### Note:

- As @Ignasi commented, the `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` need to be their own line with **nothing** else on that line (except for possibly *trailing* white space such as tabs).  No space *before* the `\end{comment}` is allowed. Even a comment `%` character seems to results in:

  > Runaway argument?
  >   ! File ended while scanning use of \next.
  >    
  >                  \par

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

%\renewenvironment{comment}{}{}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{comment}         
    \textcolor{red}{This text should NOT be displayed.}
\end{comment}    
\lipsum[2]
\begin{comment} 
    \textcolor{blue}{This text should NOT be displayed.} 
\end{comment}    
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```