# How to use the comment package within a footnote?

Tags: comments

The comment package provides for different comment environments which one can selectively in- or exclude via a switch in the preamble. I haven't found out yet how to get it to work in footnotes yet though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{note}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\footnote{A footnote.
\begin{note}
A note for myself within a footnote.
\end{note}
}
\end{document}
```

gives me the following error:

```
Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'note'
(./commentsinfootnote1.aux) Excluding 'note' comment.
! Argument of \xComment has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.10 }
```

Comment: You can't use it inside the argument of other commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It seems the `version` package can be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `version` package seems to be a drop-in replacement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{version}
\excludeversion{note}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\footnote{A footnote.
\begin{note}
A note for myself within a footnote.
\end{note}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't get this MWE to compile: `Argument of \note@NOTE has an extra }`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Strange. That was the error message I got with the `comment` package. The `version` package seems to be able to handle this.