# Is it possible to make an "if" section in TeX which is conditional on an environment version being set?

Tags: conditionals, environment-variables

I'd like to produce two slightly different versions of a document. One will include confidential information, the other will be slightly redacted.

Is it possible to use an environment variable and the `\if` command to achieve this? I will compile the document twice, but with the environment variable set and not-set depending on which version I am trying to produce?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461973/134574

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik this is great - but is there a way to turn an environment variable into a TeX variable?

Comment: It can probably be done, in one way or another. It depends on what exactly you mean by TeX variable. Can you give an example on how you want to use that variable?

Comment: The `comment` package can create environments which can be turned into comments, i.e. ignored, or included, see [How to exclude text portions by simply setting a variable or option?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28096/2975) For passing settings or a switch to the document see [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1492/2975). Both in combination should do what you want.

Comment: Also useful: [Can I access system/environment variables from LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62032/2975).