# Can I teach \censor to break on lines?

Tags: line-breaking, boxes

This is similar to [Censor text spanning multiple lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26283/17423), but I'd like to keep using the `censor` package if possible.  Its `\StopCensoring`/ `\RestartCensoring` macros and actual style of censoring (big ole' rules instead of blank space) are things I'd like to keep.

Here's an MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor}

\begin{document}
Hello, world.  \censor{This is information I would like withheld from
  public knowledge.  It is extremely sensitive.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`censor` package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/censor):

> Additionally, as of version 2.0, there is provided a block-censor capability, for redacting larger blocks of text.  This new command is `\blackout`, and is used in the form `\blackout{Block of text}`.  This nice thing about this command is that it can stretch across line and paragraph boundaries conveniently.

However, the `\blackout` command will only black out the actual words of the text, while blank spaces and periods keep visible. To overcome this, a new command was introduced:

> To this end, the `\xblackout` command is introduced in V3.10, which blacks
>   out the text more completely, while simultaneously preserving the
>   layout indentical to that of the uncensored document.

The following MWE and screenshot show the usage and respective output of the two commands in your example document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor}

\begin{document}
Hello, world.  \blackout{This is information I would like withheld from
  public knowledge.  It is extremely sensitive.}


Hello, world.  \xblackout{This is information I would like withheld from
  public knowledge.  It is extremely sensitive.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note to self: never assume the package you've been using for a decade hasn't been *updated* in a decade. Thanks!