# How to create text with shadows?

Tags: pstricks, text-decorations

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`shadowtext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shadowtext)

I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-3d,pst-text}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\pscharpath[
   shadow=true,
   shadowsize=5pt,
   shadowangle=-40,
   shadowcolor=blue,
   fillstyle=solid,
   fillcolor=black,
   linestyle=none,
   linecolor=black,
   linewidth=0pt]{\Huge SHADOW TEXT}

\end{document}
```

Problem is, there doesn't appear any shadow next to the text. Any idea how to setup shadows to a string on a way that really works?

Comment: You need to compile this with `latex+dvips`.  If you are using TeXShop, add `% !TEX TS-program = latex` as the first line of your document.
`

Comment: Okay, I tried it using TeXworks, but this way gave me `! Undefined control sequence.` errors most of the time. Don't understand why there are two tools to interpret latex. But okay, I'll use TeXShop from now on, because it works.

Comment: In TeXworks, you should be able to add `% !TeX program = latex`.  PSTricks uses Postscript commands that cannot be processed by `pdflatex` which is why you need to use `latex` when you compile this code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry for the shameless self-advertising, but I once wrote a small package for drop shadows which is now available [on CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/shadowtext); it's called `shadowtext`. This package works with pdflatex.

A somewhat long MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
%
\begin{document}
%
\setshadowoffset{1pt}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
\shadowtext{This is a shadowtext}
\end{verbatim}}
\shadowtext{This is a shadowtext}
\end{multicols*}
\end{minipage}
%
\section{Changing the position of the shadow}
%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
\setshadowoffset{2pt}
\shadowtext{This is a shadowtext}
\end{verbatim}}
%
\setshadowoffset{2pt}
\shadowtext{This is a shadowtext}
\end{multicols*}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
\shadowoffsetx=1pt
\shadowoffsety=4pt
\shadowtext{This is a shadowtext}
\end{verbatim}}
%
\shadowoffsetx=1pt
\shadowoffsety=4pt
\shadowtext{This is a shadowtext}\\
\phantom{}
\end{multicols*}
\end{minipage}
%
\section{Changing the color of the shadow}
%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
\setshadowoffset{2pt}
\setshadowcolor{0.66, 0.66, 1}
\shadowtext{This is a shadowtext}
\end{verbatim}}
%
\setshadowoffset{2pt}
\setshadowcolor{0.66, 0.66, 1}
\shadowtext{This is a shadowtext}\\
\phantom{}
\end{multicols*}
\end{minipage}
%
\section{More examples}
The following code illustrates how to use shadowtext in more interesting settings:
%
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\color{navy}
\setshadowoffset{1pt}
\shadowtext{
   \fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont
   Large!}
\end{verbatim}}
%
\color{navy}
\setshadowcolor{0.8, 0.8, 1}
\setshadowoffset{2pt}
\shadowtext{\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont \textbf{Large!}}\\
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}
\end{multicols*}
\end{minipage}
%
\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
\setshadowoffset{1pt}
\color{black}
\shadowtext{%
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
   \hline
   1 & 2 \\
   3 & 4 \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
}
\end{verbatim}}
%
\setshadowoffset{1pt}
\shadowtext{%
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
   \hline
   1 & 2 \\
   3 & 4 \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
}
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}
\end{multicols*}
(Notice the percent sign right after the shadowtext command. This is necessary!)
\end{minipage}
%    
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
\setshadowoffset{1pt}
\shadowtext{$\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-n}$}
\end{verbatim}}

\setshadowoffset{1pt}
\shadowtext{$\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-n}$}\\
\phantom{}
\end{multicols*}
\end{minipage}
%
\color{black}
%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
\color{navy}
\setshadowoffset{2pt}
\shadowtext{%
   \fontencoding{T1}%
   \fontfamily{pag}%
   \fontseries{b}%
   \fontsize{32}{32}%
   \selectfont%
   Section \arabic{section}%
}
\end{verbatim}}
%
\color{navy}%
\setshadowoffset{2pt}%
\shadowtext{%
   \fontencoding{T1}%
   \fontfamily{pag}%
   \fontseries{b}%
   \fontsize{32}{32}%
   \selectfont%
   Section \arabic{section}%
}
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}\\
\phantom{}\\
\end{multicols*}
\end{minipage}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice! Would you mind posting a small usage example and a picture of the output here? (self-advertising is fine, by the way)

Comment: +1 for sharing: Yory, that's a cute little package, please advertise more :-) You might consider adding an environment version of your `\shadowbox`.

Comment: +1 for the package. I added the examples from your `shadowbox.tex` to your answer @Yori. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: As soon as I can, I'll +1 this too. Good work! Just make your package more public, so that MacTeX users like me can use this package without manual downloading and installing. :)

Comment: @Yori Ideally you should put it on CTAN.  I would also recommend changing the name to `shadowtext` instead of `shadowbox` which seems to imply a package to put things in boxes (akin to `fancybox`.)  See [What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25116/2693) for some advice on submitting to CTAN.

Comment: Hi, wow, thanks everyone! I didn't expect so many replies. @HarishKumar: thank you for adding examples. @AlanMunn: I have no idea how to put packages on CTAN; it seems complicated to me, but I will have a look at your link (I also realized that `shadowbox` already exists and is not an appropriate name. I think `shadowtext` is a good alternative.)

Comment: I submitted a package called `shadowtext` to CTAN!

Comment: @Yori The shaded text of your package `shadowtext` looks great, but long chunks of text get frozen on a single line: wrapping seems disabled. This limits greatly the usefulness of the package.

Comment: Hi @mmj, you are right, but I do not currently have the the time to implement this. However: you can use a minipage, or perhaps you can adapt e.g. Herbert's answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25611/a-macro-that-passes-each-word-of-its-argument-to-another-macro-as-an-argument (mainly by replacing `\color{.!80}#1` by `\shadowbox{#1}`) to get close to the desired effect. Hyphenation will still not work, and I do not know off the top of my head how to make it work. Maybe someone here has a suggestion?

Comment: I managed to get some kind of word wrap replacing `\color{.!80}#1` by `\shadowtext{#1}\␣`, but it does not work well, in the sense that the result does not respect correctly text width and margins, too bad. Any more suggestion?

Comment: Some of the package commands have changed in the meantime. For instance, `\setshadowcolor` would now be `\shadowrgb` or `\shadowcolor`.

Answer (score 6):

The reason your code doesn't compile is because it uses PSTricks and you are trying to compile it with `pdflatex`.  PSTricks code uses Postcript commands that cannot be interpreted by `pdflatex`, so you need to compile it using the sequence of  `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf`.

Depending on your editor, there are different ways to do this.  Since you are using a Mac, I'll outline how to do it in both TeXShop and TeXworks.

**TeXworks**

TeXworks is not set up to be able to compile with `latex+dvips`  by default, so you first need to add to its preferences to create a "latex" compilation command.  See this question for how to do that:

[configure latexmk in Texworks 0.2.3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18936/2693)

Once you've done this, you can choose  "latex" instead of "pdfLaTeX" from the dropdown menu in the document window.

Alternatively, you can put

```
% !TeX program = latex
```

as the first line of your file.

**TeXShop**

In TeXShop, you need to choose "TeX and DVI" from the Typeset menu instead of "pdfTeX".

Alternatively, you can put

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
```

as the first line of your file.

Comment: Thanks for your help! A bit more configurations were needed to get a "latex" option in the dropdown menu and `% !TeX program = latex` didn't worked without adding the "latex" option to the dropdown menu. But in TeXShop I had no issues with that and it already worked without changing "pdfTeX" to "TeX and DVI" in the Typeset menu.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike some other answers, the result is not in a box, and so it can work across line-breaks, paragraph breaks, and page breaks.

In that sense, it is somewhat like Karl's answer.  But unlike Karl's answer, it can be interspersed with normal text on a word by word basis.  Ligatures are, however, lost.

The settable options are:

```
\setlength\shadowHoffset{.3pt}
\setlength\shadowVoffset{-.2pt}
\def\primarycolor{white}
\def\secondarycolor{black}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}

\newcommand\shadowfy[1]{\expandafter\shadowfypars#1\par\relax\relax}
\long\def\shadowfypars#1\par#2\relax{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \shadowfywords#1 \relax\relax%
  \fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\par\shadowfypars#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\shadowfywords#1 #2\relax{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \shadowfyletters#1\relax\relax%
  \fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \shadowfywords#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\shadowfyletters#1#2\relax{%
  \shadow{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\shadowfyletters#2\relax\fi}

\newlength\shadowHoffset
\newlength\shadowVoffset
\setlength\shadowHoffset{.3pt}
\setlength\shadowVoffset{-.2pt}
\def\primarycolor{white}
\def\secondarycolor{black}

\def\shadow#1{\kern\shadowHoffset%
  \raisebox{\shadowVoffset}{%
  \stackinset{c}{-\shadowHoffset}{c}{-\shadowVoffset}%
  {\textcolor{\primarycolor}{#1}}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}}%
  \kern-\shadowHoffset}

\begin{document}
\def\mytext{%
Problem is, there doesn't appear any shadow next to the text. Any idea how to 
setup shadows to a string on a way that really works?

And for my second paragraph, the problem is, there doesn't appear any shadow 
next to the text. Any idea how to setup shadows to a string on a way that 
really works?
}%
\shadowfy{\mytext}

\def\primarycolor{black}%
\def\secondarycolor{black!30}%
\setlength\shadowHoffset{.3pt}
\setlength\shadowVoffset{-.3pt}
\shadowfy{\mytext}

\def\shadowVoffset{-1pt}%
And it should line up with text: \shadowfy{\mytext}

\LARGE\sffamily%
\def\primarycolor{blue!70!black}%
\def\secondarycolor{cyan!25}%
\def\shadowHoffset{.5pt}%
\def\shadowVoffset{-.8pt}%
And color: \shadowfy{\mytext}
\end{document}
```

Here is somewhat of a zoom on the result:

[image]

Here I demonstrate line and paragraph breaking.

[image]

Here is a mid-line transition from normal to shadow text, exaggerated shadowing to demonstrate that the primary baselines line up.

[image]

And here is color:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another option, if you are looking for multiline shadow text is to use the textpos package to create a textblock of the main text and then offset the box slightly to create the 'shadow' portion.  Note, the 'gray' text needs to be created first so the black text can overlay it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\TPGrid{100}{100}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\begin{textblock}{70}(10.2,4.1)
\Huge{\color{Gray}\lipsum[66]}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{70}(10,4)
\Huge\lipsum[66]
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

This works great for multiline titles on reports, etc.

Here's an example: [image: example]