# Letterpress effect through PSTricks or Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have already typed in the `META` section of the website a post addressing the question as to how the letterpress (or engraving-like) effect in the headers of the site had been achieved. I know it can be done with vector graphics GUI-driven software (such as Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator and those of their ilk). I do not despise those applications at all (rather on the contrary), but I do my graphic work with `PSTricks` or `Tikz` (or even `Asymptote`) for precisely the same kind of reasons that I use TeX-based typesetting systems, as opposed to other high-quality systems such as Adobe InDesign or Quark.

Somebody at the `META` section suggested that maybe I should ask about this point in this section, and here I am. Anyone could say if there is a way that such an effect can be done with our beloved packages (those I have mentioned above)? Of course, it can be done going to the PostScript level, but I'm asking about a more direct way that is already available.

EDIT: Alan's answer below works fine. We get a letterpress effect indeed, but I believe it is not the same kind of effect that has been achieved in the header. `Caramdir` has answered in the `META`section that it was not done on TeX -- I understand he means it was done with some GUI-driven application. Anyone knows how to do this with code based on `PSTricks`, `Tikz` or `Asymptote`?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how the solution proposed by Alan differs from the graphics in the header?

Comment: In the headers we don't have a shadow dropped by the typefaces which is lighter than the background color. What I understand we have instead is something like a darker hue inside the typefaces themselves. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: There's no typo in my code.  You must have changed the document class to `memoir` (which defines its own version of `\HUGE`.)

Comment: Alan, you're right. I am so used to working with `memoir` that I didn't realize `\HUGE` was actually introduced in it. I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Followed you here from the meta post. Herbert and Alan's answers came very close. I just want to point out that in the site logo, I had the white drop shadow, as well as a darker inner shadow inside of the letters. Light source set to 120 degrees. Here's a [larger version](http://i.imgur.com/uTGsX.png) of the logo.

Comment: @Herbert: Is it possible to achieve this effect with the current facilities provided by the `PSTricks`-based packages?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a pure TikZ/PGF version.  Needs a bit of work to get the effect as good as the original image.  It uses a couple of bits of code from the [TeX-SX launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files): the letter shape package and the shadow blur package (note: there's a minor modification of this compared to the [`pgf-blur`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-blur) package on CTAN).

The idea is to *draw* the letter with a shadow but to have the shadow drawn on top of the letter rather than under it to give the effect that it is the surrounding paper that is causing the shadow rather than the letter.  The `shapes.letter` tikzlibrary is needed to define paths corresponding to letters and the `pgf-blur` library is for the blurred shadow.

Given those two packages, here's the code to produce the effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62570/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.letters,shadows.blur}

\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/letter/.cd,
  load font={stikz}{normal},
  size=4,
  load encoding=char,
}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  use letter path/.code={%
    \pgfscope
    \pgftransformscale{\letter@size}%
    \letter@path{\letter@encode{#1}}%
    \endpgfscope
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\fill[red!70!black,use letter path=T];
\path[blur shadow,shadow blur base colour=white,use letter path=T];
\begin{scope}[shift={(2cm,-.8cm)}]
\fill[red!70!black,use letter path=E];
\path[blur shadow,shadow blur base colour=white,use letter path=E];
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(4.1cm,0)}]
\fill[red!70!black,use letter path=X];
\path[blur shadow,shadow blur base colour=white,use letter path=X];
\end{scope}
\path (current bounding box.north west) ++(-1,1)  (current bounding
box.south east) ++(1,-1);
\clip[use letter path=T] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle
(current bounding box.south east);
\clip[shift={(2cm,-.8cm)},use letter path=E] (current bounding
box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
\clip[shift={(4.1cm,0cm)},use letter path=X] (current bounding
box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
\fill[blue,rounded corners] (current bounding box.north west)
rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result (I didn't spend any time getting the colours right):

[image: Psuedo-sunken letters]

Comment: The `pgf-blur` package came into being from this package: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50422/86

Comment: Alternatively, one could paint a light red background, and the blue shape minus the letters (some winding number trick) with a standard black blur shadow on top.

Comment: @mabartibin Duh ... now why didn't I think of that?

Comment: because you were subconsciously waiting for an excuse to have something cast a white shadow ;-)

Comment: @mabartibin That'll be it.  Actually I decided I didn't like this method and went for an "inverse shadow" instead (see latest code on launchpad).

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Thanks for your answer. It is very nice indeed, although I'd rather have a PSTricks-based answer since that's the kind of setting I'm more used to. Your answer deserves the award anyway.

Comment: @Marcos I understand it's not quite what you're looking for, I knew that when I posted it.  For questions like this, I can envisage lots of people thinking "I want something like this but I want to use package XYZ instead".  Then, I'd rather have all the answers in *one* place than lots of variants of essentially the same question.  I should have said that at the start!  So I'm pleased you like it and I hope someone can translate it to PSTricks for you - it should be possible.

Comment: The output is really impressive, it looks as if you used a raytracing software!

Comment: May I ask where is the `shadow blur base colour` parameter defined? It looks that the base code changed over the years.

Answer (score 18):

needs `pdflatex -shell-escape` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% for running it with pdflatex -shell-escape
\usepackage{pst-light3d}
\DeclareFixedFont{\Sf}{T1}{fxb}{b}{n}{2cm}
\begin{document}

\psframebox[framesep=5mm,fillcolor=black!20,fillstyle=solid]{%
  \PstLightThreeDText[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white,linestyle=none,
    LightThreeDYLength=0.1]{\Sf \rule[-0.75cm]{0pt}{2.5cm}Letterpress}}

\psframebox[framesep=5mm,fillcolor=black!20,fillstyle=solid]{%
  \PstLightThreeDText[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black!70,linestyle=none,
    LightThreeDYLength=-0.07,LightThreeDColorPsCommand=pop 1 setgray,
    LightThreeDXLength=0]{\Sf \rule[-0.75cm]{0pt}{2.5cm}Letterpress}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Herbert, thanks so much. I'm afraid what you get is the 3D effect which turns out to be the (in a sense) "opposite" to the letterpress effect. I would think that PSTricks is powerful enough to achieve the headers effect without needing to go all the way down to the PostScript level, but so far I haven't figured out the how-to and I guess you're the one who knows best.

Comment: see edit, I had the wrong setting for the second example.

Comment: It works like Alan's Tikz-based code, but if you could possibly see the edit to my original question... I still think this does not make for the effect on the headers -- which does not detract from my appreciation for your assistance.

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve a poor-man's letterpress effect by using text with a slight shadow set on an appropriately coloured background. This is how the effect is implemented in CSS. In this example I've used TikZ only to produce the background. The shadows are produced with the nice `shadowbox` package, first announced in this question:

[How to create text with shadows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53369/2693)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
% fontspec requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newcommand\HUGE{\fontsize{2cm}{2cm}\selectfont}
% The regular shadowtext command to set colours is \shadowcolor
% but the command allows input only in rgb triples
% The following command allows for xcolor named values to be used
% and is much more convenient
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setshadowcolor[1]{\colorlet{st@shadowcolor}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\shadowoffsety{1pt}
\shadowoffsetx{0pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=black!50,minimum height=3cm] 
     {\setshadowcolor{black!30}\shadowtext{\bfseries\HUGE Letterpress}};
\begin{scope}[yshift=3cm]
\node[fill=black!40,minimum height=3cm] 
     {\setshadowcolor{black}\shadowtext{\color{white}\bfseries\HUGE Letterpress}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(The image doesn't look very nice because of the conversion to `.png`.)

[image: output of code]