# Embossed and debossed text

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Letterpress effect through PSTricks or Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62570/letterpress-effect-through-pstricks-or-tikz)

Can one produce embossed and debossed text in LaTeX? (E.g. using Tikz.)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the following question [Letterpress effect through TikZ or PSTricks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62570/2693) is a duplicate?