# How to convert font file to a series of Bézier curves?

Tags: fonts, svg, fontforge

While we are solving this question [How to get intersection point(s) of two glyphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180510/how-to-get-intersection-points-of-two-glyphs), we are facing some interesting subproblems. This is the first one. How we could convert any font file (OTF, TTF, PFB, ...) to a series of Bézier curves, ideally loadable by TikZ?

We can view control points of cubic Bézier curves in FontForge's native format ([SFD](http://fontforge.org/sfdformat.html)) or we can save font file to SVG and then it can be converted to TikZ ([svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) known as inkscape2tikz), but it's probably not that simple as we want to preserve character names.

I've found some inspiration by [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) in [Letterpress effect through PSTricks or Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62570/letterpress-effect-through-pstricks-or-tikz). I can prove his approach is working as should be in case of the STIX font family.