# How do I compile the shapes.letters package from the TeX-SX Launchpad site

Tags: tikz-pgf

In a few places on this site, such as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62570/letterpress-effect-through-pstricks-or-tikz), the `shapes.letters` package is mentioned:

I would like to use it. So I download `pgflibraryshapes.letters.dtx` from [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files), and try to compile it. How do I do this? If I hit it with latex I get 'LaTeX error: Missing \begin{document}', and if I hit it with tex I get 'missing $ inserted'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to instal `tikz` (and load it `\usepackage{tikz}`)

Comment: I know that, but I haven't even got to that stage! I'm talking about compiling the .dtx file into a .sty.

Comment: @AndrewStacey notifying a regular...

Comment: @LoopSpace notifying another regular...

Comment: @JamieVicary pinging like that only works if the user has commented on or edited the specific post.

Answer (score 1):

This basic sequence is how to proceed in general and it worked for me for the file in question:

- Download the file into some directory searched by TeX and not under the control of a package manager (for example, `$TEXMFHOME` for TeX Live).
- Try to maintain a structure consistent with the main installation tree. For example, for this file, I'd place it at `$TEXMFHOME/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/` to use the same file structure for `shapes` libraries as the packaged shape libraries in the main install tree.
- Open your favorite terminal and navigate to this directory. Run `latex pgflibraryshapes.letters.dtx` (possibly twice to resolve references in the documentation). Several files are generated, already in the correct place.
- Now the new library can be used with `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.letters}` in any of your documents. You can inspect the log file to ensure that the file is being found successfully. On my system, I got this line in the log file:

> ```
> c:/Users/<username>/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.letters.code.tex
> ```