# Text make the path of a letter

Tags: tikz-styles, text

How can a text make the path of a letter, for example, letter **"S"**?
Instead of taking a circle like for the following code:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
%\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
    \DeclareFixedFont{\pb}{T1}{pbk}{b}{n}{5cm}
    
    \mbox{}
    \begin{textblock*}{200mm}[0.2,0.5](67mm,33mm)
        
        \catcode`\|12
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %\draw [help lines] (4,4)grid (0,2);
            \fill [draw=none,fill=none,
            postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=8pt,text along path,
                    text=around and around and around and around we go we go we go we go we go we go we go we go we go we go we go}}]
            (0,1) arc (180:-180:3.5cm and 2.4cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ages ago I converted some letters to TikZ paths to use with decorations, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66091/86.  I suspect that there are easier ways now than back then, but would that sort of thing help?

Comment: Sorry teacher, I couldn't do what you told me because Because I am still new to "tikz".

Comment: Actually, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21594/86 might be more what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

The code's a bit old, so is not guaranteed to be robust.  It needs some files from the old [TeX-SX Launchpad project](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Etex-sx/tex-sx/development/files):

- `pgflibraryshapes.letters.dtx` after downloading run `tex pgflibraryshapes.letters.dtx` to generate the necessary files
- `stikz-normal-paths.tex` to load the paths for the STIX fonts

It seems to only work with `pdflatex` (not `lualatex`), possibly due to some bad encoding choices in some of the files.  So it shouldn't be difficult to fix that.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614684/86}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes.letters,
  decorations.text,
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\emcm}{1em/1cm}
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/letter/.cd,
%  load font={stikz}{italic},
  load font={stikz}{normal},
  size=10,
  load encoding=char,
  every letter/.append style={
    fill,
  },
  sentence width=.9\textwidth,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[letter=S,
    decorate,
    decoration={
      raise=8pt,
      text along path,
      text={Round and round the garden
        Like a teddy bear;
        One step, two step,
        Tickle you under there!
      Round and round the garden
        Like a teddy bear;
        One step, two step,
        Tickle you under there!
      Round and round the garden
        Like a teddy bear;
        One step, two step,
        Tickle you under there!}
    }
] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text around a letter S]