# A macro that passes each word of its argument to another macro as an argument (again)

Tags: macros

I know that this is a duplicate to [A macro that passes each word of its argument to another macro as an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25611/a-macro-that-passes-each-word-of-its-argument-to-another-macro-as-an-argument), that's why I kept the title, but I didn't manage to get the right result when the argument that contained the words is given also as a macro.

See the code below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}%
\begin{document}

\def\somefigures{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}
\def\wbox#1{\boxw#1 \empty}
\def\boxw#1 #2{\fbox{#1}\ \ifx #2\empty\else\expandafter\boxw\fi #2}

\wbox{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}\bigskip

\wbox{\somefigures}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're short some expansion inside `\wbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%
\begin{document}

\def\somefigures{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}
\def\wbox#1{\expandafter\boxw#1 \empty}% expanded #1 first
\def\boxw#1 #2{\fbox{#1}\ \ifx #2\empty\else\expandafter\boxw\fi #2}

\wbox{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}\bigskip

\wbox{\somefigures}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming that there is no issue with the expansion of tokens, of course: don't try `\wbox{\textbf}` for example.

Comment: It worked. What if I want something like `\wbox{\textbf{\somefigures}}` (following what @JosephWright said)?

Comment: @digital-Ink Use `\textbf{\wbox{\somefigures}}`