# How can I get multiline outlined/shaded text in LaTeX?

Tags: highlighting, wrap

How can I get multiline text highlighted by means of outlining or shading? I found some solutions ([contour](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/contour), [shadowtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shadowtext), [pdf-trans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21586/28685)) but none able to wrap multiline text.

Some examples of outlined and shaded text:

[image]

[image]

**OUTLINED TEXT FOLLOW UP**

See [below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108870/28685) for solution.

**SHADED TEXT FOLLOW UP** (STILL SEEKING FOR A DEFINITIVE SOLUTION)

***Possible solution #1***

A promising solution for people like me compiling with `pdflatex` (and `-shell-escape` option) looks this one (MWE adapted from Herbert's nice answer, here implementing a user-defined `shadetext` command):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-text,pst-blur}

\newcommand{\shadetext}[1]{% compile with pdflatex -shell-escape
\begin{postscript}
\pscharpath[
      shadow=true,
      shadowsize=.1em,
      shadowangle=-40,
      shadowcolor=gray,
      fillstyle=solid,
      fillcolor=black,
      linestyle=none,
      linecolor=black,
      linewidth=0pt
]{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1}}
\end{postscript}
}

\begin{document}
\shadetext{Text to be shaded.} Unshaded text.
\end{document}
```

Such solution has multiline wrapping and hypenation too, but has got a major (at least for me) and a minor problem. The big problem is that it does not compile if you use the `babel` package (I have `\usepackage[greek,italian]{babel}` in my preamble), preventing you from using it altoghether. The small problem is that if you mix shaded and normal text, the result is far from perfect (and sometimes even messy, it depends on how you mix shaded and normal text):

[image]

***Possible solution #2***

I got somewhat closer to solution for shaded text, using `shadowtext` package and the following code (adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25613/28685)) in the preamble, to automatically apply shadow (through newly defined command `\wordshadow`) to each single word of the argument (`␣` is to be replaced by a space char):

```
\makeatletter
\def\wordshadow#1{\expandafter\wordshadow@i#1 \@nil}
\def\wordshadow@i#1 #2\@nil{%
  \shadowtext{#1}\␣
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\wordshadow@i#2\@nil\fi}
\makeatother
```

but the result, although better than no wrap at all, is not perfect, as you can see below:

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Answer might be difficult but I think the question is simple and clear. I can only add an example of outlined and shaded text, although I think it does not add any information.

Comment: Have you seen this : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex ?

Comment: @percusse Yes, but I'm interested only in outlined and shaded text. For other types of highlighting multiline wrapping works.

Comment: I think what percusse is saying is that the solution to the linked question could be adapted to this question.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang It might be, but as a simple LaTeX user I don't know how. I think outlining and shading are important features (other softwares have such features since ages), and if someone knows how to make those solutions wrap multiline text, I hope they will share their knowledge and improve LaTeX.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Package `pdfrender` is able to "highlight" text (except for PK fonts) that can be broken across lines and even pages:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\textpdfrender{
  TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
  FillColor=red,
  LineWidth=.07ex,
}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I was looking for, and `pdflatex` compiles it as I need. Thanks! Hope someone comes out with a solution for shaded text too.

Answer (score 5):

it cannot have a pagebreak and works only with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. XeTeX cannot handle blurred shadows:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-text,pst-blur}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pscharpath[shadow,blur]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \section{foo}
    \large\lipsum[2]}}
\end{document}
```

or for `pdflatex --shell-escape` use

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}% for pdflatex --shell-escape
\usepackage{pst-text,pst-blur}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}% for pdflatex --shell-escape
\pscharpath[shadow,blur]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \section{foo}
    \large\lipsum[2]}}
\end{postscript}% for pdflatex --shell-escape
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I currently compile using `pdflatex`, since I'm not an expert can you explain me better the steps I need to take to use your solution?

Comment: see my edit. The second example can be run with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`. But it takes some time to run.

Comment: Nice one, it works (almost) great, but I have still some issues, the biggest one seems to be an incompatibility with `babel` package, see my follow up in the question.

Comment: that looks like a problem with the italian language and the defined shorthand of `"`