# How pdfrender package can have the same output like simple contour

Tags: contour

I am trying to use simple contour for a text. Unfortunately, as the text is inside an element and multiline, I was forced to use alternatives (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104211/contour-around-multi-line-tikz-text/108875#108875) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108863/how-can-i-get-multiline-outlined-shaded-text-in-latex)). Using *pdfrender* package almost works, but the "boundaries" of the text invade inside (unlike *contour*). Like this:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{pdfrender}      
\contourlength{1pt}
    
\begin{document}
\color{green}\sffamily\bfseries\Huge
\contour{black}{ABP} 
\textpdfrender{TextRenderingMode=FillStroke, FillColor=green, StrokeColor=black, LineWidth=1pt}{ABP}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Tring to use different *Linewidth* was not solving the problem. I wonder is there any way that *pdfrender* would elicit the same output as the *contour*?

Comment: lapsus: "pdflatex package"  `:-)`  Afaik there are no way to make an outer contour instead of a inner contour with pdfrender, but a dirty solution could be to use a bolder font. In fact, it could be even better, as this will maintain the right space between characters.

Comment: @Fran, thanks for noting. I'll try using bold. (novice in Latex)