# Justify text when using a tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

I'm using

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\addtolength{\columnsep}{0.4cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{\columnsep}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & Aron climbed down a narrow gap between  \\
2 & the walls of the canyon. Suddenly a large  \\
3 & rock fell on his right arm. It trapped his arm  \\
4 & against the canyon wall. He tried to pull is  \\
5 & arm out, but the rock weighed 360 kilograms.\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have the four lines of each long text justified, is there way to accomplish this?

---

I've added a more complete example to show what I want.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `tabular` for this? Are you trying to number lines? There's no way to justify each line without awful interword spacing.

Comment: I'll upload a photo so that you can see the result I want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is what you want, but it will ultimately look awful (or a LaTeX imitation of MSWord...)

To number the lines, I've just made a counter, which will save you some typing. For the spacing, I've used a [macro from Bruno LeFloch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25704/2693) which splits space delimited text and applies a macro to it. I've then appended `\hfill` to each word in the cell, using the `collectcell` package.  This fills out each line with as much space as needed to fill the line width.  Ugh. :)

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% This macro based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25704/
\NewDocumentCommand {\hfillspace}
  { > { \SplitList { ~ } } m }
  { \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} { ##1\hfill } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{myline}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{myline}{0}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{myline}\themyline\quad\collectcell\hfillspace}p{.9\columnwidth}<{\endcollectcell}}
Aron climbed down a narrow gap between\\
the walls of the canyon. Suddenly a large\\
rock fell on his right arm. It trapped his arm\\
against the canyon wall. He tried to pull is\\
arm out, but the rock weighed 360 kilograms. 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]