How to ignore Arabic font for line spacing in inline Latin and Arabic text with Xelatex and babel?
I have a document with inline Latin and Arabic text. I'm using Xelatex and Babel.
For more information, I'm actually using Bookdown/Rmarkdown which uses pandoc so I'm somewhat, but not completely, restricted in what packages I can use, and how I can use them. But that's an aside.
When Arabic is inline with Latin text, the Arabic font's ascenders, descenders, and diacritics cause Tex to have non-uniform line-spacing, which looks unappealing to me. Here is an example:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
% get rid of language-specific shorthands:
\let\LanguageShortHands\languageshorthands
\def\languageshorthands#1{}

\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Vazirmatn-Light}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{Vazirmatn-Light}

% pandoc default latex templete uses this:
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺈِﻧَّ} and its sisters}
\begin{enumerate}
\tightlist
\item
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺈِﻧَّ} \emph{ʾinna}
\item
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺄَﻧَّ} \emph{ʾanna}
\item
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﮎَﺄَﻧَّ} \emph{kaʾanna}
\item
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﻞَـٰﮑِﻧَّ} \emph{lākinna}
\item
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﻞَﻴْﺗَ} \emph{layta}
\item
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﻞَﻌَﻟَّ} \emph{laʿalla}
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{The lightened versions \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺈِﻧْ}, \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺄَﻧْ}, \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﮎَﺄَﻧْ}, and \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﻞَـٰﮑِﻧْ}}

The particles \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺈِﻧَّ}, \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺄَﻧَّ}, \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﮎَﺄَﻧَّ}, and \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﻞَـٰﮑِﻧَّ}, because of the doubled \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﻥّ} are considered \emph{heavy}.
There exist \emph{lightened} versions of these particles that are:
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺈِﻧْ}, \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺄَﻧْ}, \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﮎَﺄَﻧْ}, and \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﻞَـٰﮑِﻧْ}.
These lightened versions have similar meanings to their heavy counterparts but they have somewhat different rules. We will discuss them below.
In terms of their usage
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺈِﻧْ} and
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﮎَﺄَﻧْ} are not very commonly used except in the Qurʾān, poetry, and other rhetorical texts.
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﺄَﻧْ} and
\foreignlanguage{arabic}{ﻞَـٰﮑِﻧْ}
are relatively more common.

\end{document}

This results in the following output:

How do I force Tex to ignore the Arabic font when determining line-spacing, even it results in possible collisions. I would prefer not to decrease the size of the Arabic font.
I tried setting \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen as some had suggested this but it completely destroys linespacing in tables and around tikzpictures. (Not sure if pandoc issue.)

I don’t think it’s possible in a general way with pdftex or xetex. Very likely it can be done with luatex, but I can’t say for sure. So a dirty hack.
WARNING. This interface isn’t documented because it’s not final, so use it at your own risk. It may change in the future and replaced by a better syntax.
For single words, you can declare a hook in the following way:
\AddBabelHook[arabic]{smash}{foreign}{\def\BabelText##1{\smash{##1}}}

Note \smash boxes the text, so there won’t be line breaks.

Thank you. This looks good. Would it make sense to come up with some sort of a loop over the space-separated input words and smash them individually? This is so that it can help with the line breaking.

@coderoo Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25611/a-macro-that-passes-each-word-of-its-argument-to-another-macro-as-an-argument
