# \boxed{}, TikZ and colored equation background

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, amsmath, highlighting

I wonder if someone could provide me with a simple MWE for using TikZ together with `\boxed` to produce a colored equation background. If possible with rounded corners.

I am using `\boxed{}` inside the `split` environment from `amsmath`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are some packages that can help you, for example:

- [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq)
- [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz)

and along this site some answers could be a good starting point:

- [Highlight an equation within an align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13681/highlight-an-equation-within-an-align-environment?lq=1)
- [Highlight an equation within an align environment with color option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/highlight-an-equation-within-an-align-environment-with-color-option)
- [Black and white emphasis for \boxed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42315/black-and-white-emphasis-for-boxed)

Here, I provide you a MWE using the [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package. Actually `\boxed{}` is not used at all, thus I don't know if this will meet your requirements. Notice that, in the following example, it is shown how to highlight the whole equation or just a part of it, that is the major potentiality of the package. You should compile twice to get the right result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq}\begin{split}\tikzmarkin{a}(0.2,-0.5)(-0.2,0.65)
H_c&=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{split}\end{equation}

\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{blue}
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq2}\begin{split}
H_c&=\tikzmarkin{b}(0,-0.6)(0,0.65)\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\tikzmarkend{b}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].
\end{split}\end{equation}

\hfsetfillcolor{green!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{green!50!black}
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq3}\begin{split}
H_c&=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\tikzmarkin{c}(0.05,-0.6)(-0.05,0.65)\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].\tikzmarkend{c}
\end{split}\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

According to the request in the comments, here are the two possibilities to get rigid corners. It is needed the version `0.2` of the package.

- The option `norndcorners` to have always rigid corners: just loading the package with `\usepackage[customcolors,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}` the previous document becomes:

[image]

- The second possibility allows to have rigid corners singularly; load the package with the `shade` option and then use the key `disable rounded corners=true` in the `tikzmarkin` command.

In this example, the second equation is highlighted with rigid corners while the other two with rounded corners:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq}\begin{split}\tikzmarkin{a}(0.2,-0.5)(-0.2,0.65)
H_c&=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{split}\end{equation}

\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{blue}
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq2}\begin{split}
H_c&=\tikzmarkin[disable rounded corners=true]{b}(0,-0.6)(0,0.65)\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\tikzmarkend{b}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].
\end{split}\end{equation}

\hfsetfillcolor{green!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{green!50!black}
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq3}\begin{split}
H_c&=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
\sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
\tikzmarkin{c}(0.05,-0.6)(-0.05,0.65)\Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].\tikzmarkend{c}
\end{split}\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have rigid corners instead of rounded ones?

Comment: @smh: sorry, unfortunately at the moment the package does not provide that functionality. I will try see if there is a simple way to insert it :)

Comment: @smh: I've updated the package (version 0.2) and now there's the possibility to disable rounded corners in two manners: globally with the option `norndcorners` or just for one box, and in that case there's a specific procedure (details in section 3.5).

Answer (score 27):

I think the best solution was already provided by Claudio. I am only putting this here to do something about that `\boxed` command. But I think this solution will not work with split environment so this does not really answer your question. As pointed out already, you may better use the solution by Claudio or use `empheq` package instead.

Here is what I came up with.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% put color to \boxed math command
\newcommand*{\boxcolor}{orange}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\boxed}[1]{\textcolor{\boxcolor}{%
\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-1ex]current bounding box.center)}] \node [rectangle, minimum width=1ex,rounded corners,draw] {\normalcolor\m@th$\displaystyle#1$};}}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\boxed{ax^2+bx+c}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_{1,2}=\boxed{\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may tweak to your liking.

Comment: It works with split command. THX.

Comment: It doesn't work with multi-line equations

Comment: @smh How do you use it? It is not meant to be used to frame multi-line equations at all but it works with the `split` environment (just as well as the unmodified `\boxed` command) although that was not my intention when I wrote this. I was just toying with the command to learn how to write and redefine `LaTeX` macros. Try `\begin{equation} x=\boxed{\begin{split}...\end{split}}\end{equation}`