# How to highlight math environments with colored background?

Tags: math-mode, color, highlighting

How to highlight maths environments (in-line mode excluded) with a coloured rectangular background e.g. grey?

A `\textwidth` rectangular **behind** the `{equation}` environment.

Comment: have you seen [these questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=framed+equations&submit=search)?

Comment: There's actually a very similar question: [\boxed{}, TikZ and colored equation background](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75129/boxed-tikz-and-colored-equation-background), but what do you mean with _The rectangular is expected to be below the equation_? Do the answers provided in the question I linked satisfy you (besides the point of highlighting also the equation counter, but for that I could provide you an answer)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to use [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) and surround the equation environments.

[image: equation]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\surroundwithmdframed[
    hidealllines=true,
    backgroundcolor=black!20,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip,
    skipabove=\baselineskip
]{equation}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
Text
\end{document}
```

---

**Extended version**

To add the background also to `\[ … \]` some more code is necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% define a style
\mdfdefinestyle{mathbackground}{
    hidealllines=true,
    backgroundcolor=black!20,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip,
    skipabove=\baselineskip,
    innertopmargin=1pt,
}

% add it to {equation}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=mathbackground]{equation}
% ... similar for other environments

% add the environment to \[\] (needs etoolbox)
\preto{\[}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=mathbackground]%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}
\appto{\]}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}
Text

Text
\[
1+1=2
\]
Text
\end{document}
```

But use this with care I’m not sure if there are any drawbacks. Take it as a *quick & dirty* solution …

Comment: Thanks Tobi. This is exactly what I meant, but I'm writing my report in **book class**.
I tried your code. It seems it doesn't work in this class.

Comment: @MilO: Sorry but I can’t reproduce your errer. If I just replace `article` with `book` everything works fine. What’s the error message you get?

Comment: Is there a way I could use this as in a shortcut equation like `\[ a = 1 \]`?

Comment: @hoeni: See my edit. But I’m not sure if this has any drawbacks or fuses other problems …

Comment: @Tobi works fine! Had to do some space tuning due to my LaTex Beamer Environment, but I can see the principle, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I really didn't follow

> The rectangular is expected to be below the equation and also the
>   equation counter. In better words `\textwidth`.

Hence this answer ;) I don't know to what extent this will be useful to anybody. But for the sake of it, I present the following:

This solution uses `etoolbox` with its `\AfterEndEnvironment` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{{\tikz\draw[fill=black!20,draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, .3);}\par}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the "below" in the question should be "behind"

Comment: @egreg: hehe. If that is the case Tobi has already answered it. Let this answer be for fun ;)

Comment: Also "empheq" (http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/empheq.html) from the "mh" bundle er useful for something like this.

Comment: Do you know that you can use `\fill[black!20]` instead of `\draw[fill=black!20,draw=none]` ;-)

Comment: 'er' --> 'is' ... I hate it when I mix Danish and English!

Comment: Thanks you mentioned Egreg. Honestly speaking I carelessly wrote the word 'below' instead of the correct word 'behind' which might have caused to a misunderstandings.