# Highlighting all elements of type in the document

Tags: highlighting, preamble, formulas

I would like to know if there's a command that I can use in the preamble to highlight all elements of a given type in a colour of my choosing. I would particularly like to highlight all math formulae. If this is not possible, I would also be nice a command that colours all the formulae (or elements of a give type).

What I don't want is for each element to be highlighted individually, unless there's an automatic way to do so.

```
\documentclass{article}

% This option of this fictitious package highlights all formulae in yellow
\usepackage[formula=yellow]{highlighter}
    
% This unused command would have highlighted all numbers in cyan.
%\usepackage[number=cyan]{highlighter}


\begin{document}
    
    This is a formula that will be highlighted:

    $$(x+y)^2 &= x^2 + 2xy + y^2$$

    Also the following formula will be highlighted:

    \begin{align*}
        (x+y)^2 &= x^2 + y^2
    \end{align*}

    And so will be  $x^2 + y^2 = (x+y)^2$, because all formulas will be highlighted.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible but difficult. Half of the question is explained in [formatting - How to highlight all inline math in document? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135053/how-to-highlight-all-inline-math-in-document).

Comment: I think [How to color certain commands/environments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135066/how-to-color-certain-commands-environments?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [color - How to highlight math environments with colored background? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77762/how-to-highlight-math-environments-with-colored-background) will handle the environment part.