# Equation on papyrus with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

**First of all to apologize for my English.**

So, many times when I teach on the board used to include  the final result
on papyrus (and that likes too students). 
Just I think that would be a good idea to do it and
at my notes.

---

**So my question:** 
How can I get one papyrus inside to have a mathematical
relationship or a text. I want to create something  maybe whith TikZ that listens to commands

```
\papyrustrue % on the preamble

\startpapyrus
 $ E = m c^2 $
\stoppapyrus
```

The `\papyrustrue` will switch to the papyrus displayed or not (if I comment it out 
`%\papyrustrue`).
 Certainly the mathematical relationship I always want to appear. I mean if
I comment out the `\papyrustrue` not disappear and the relationship but only
the papyrus. Rather it should be the papyrus as a layer over the ralationship
 ( .... that's what I think, maybe this idea is wrong)

At the final result I imagine something like this ( sorry for handmade figure, if I 
knew how to do it will not ask you, currently the score is: papyrus - karathan = 1 - 0 :-) )
I have seen this

[\boxed{}, TikZ and colored equation background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75129/boxed-tikz-and-colored-equation-background)

but if on LateX I am relatively new I am ultimately irrelevant on TikZ

[image]

---

I know my question sounds rather do this for me, and I don't feel good for it... but I don't know what else to do...

Of course, I would like to hear your opinion if the idea of the papyrus is 
something worthwhile.

---

Here I put the stolen code from jpgfdrew than I use, but
certainly that no help very much .

Just think maybe through the jpgfdraw and flowframe that it include maybe to manage something . . . but rather I try in vain without results ... .... never mind I survive without papyrus :-)

the score is: papyrus - karathan = 2 - 0

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{0bp}{420.849709bp}{179.390961bp}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{32.278702bp}{137.07737bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{5.113533bp}{147.962151bp}}{\pgfpoint{26.937674bp}{155.673503bp}}{\pgfpoint{37.413107bp}{145.194173bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{45.642968bp}{139.580246bp}}{\pgfpoint{46.640999bp}{127.003489bp}}{\pgfpoint{34.337142bp}{127.252997bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{0.747145bp}{137.108558bp}}{\pgfpoint{-15.689186bp}{157.100377bp}}{\pgfpoint{34.150011bp}{161.778649bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{103.887462bp}{161.404387bp}}{\pgfpoint{428.247698bp}{121.857389bp}}{\pgfpoint{415.897059bp}{164.398482bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{404.575639bp}{186.604683bp}}{\pgfpoint{351.368085bp}{173.848593bp}}{\pgfpoint{370.704945bp}{159.720209bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{403.140969bp}{148.211659bp}}{\pgfpoint{410.71977bp}{167.236634bp}}{\pgfpoint{387.453161bp}{167.766838bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{37.892612bp}{39.289968bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{107.630063bp}{38.915706bp}}{\pgfpoint{431.990299bp}{-1.754077bp}}{\pgfpoint{419.63966bp}{40.787015bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4.343639bp}{143.814082bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{25.92607bp}{73.0786bp}}{\pgfpoint{7.462488bp}{43.387163bp}}{\pgfpoint{2.846592bp}{23.301779bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{15.44674bp}{3.216395bp}}{\pgfpoint{48.631287bp}{-3.146055bp}}{\pgfpoint{42.144082bp}{12.448187bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{39.898511bp}{59.729929bp}}{\pgfpoint{31.914259bp}{104.391838bp}}{\pgfpoint{41.76982bp}{128.469348bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{35.532123bp}{127.097055bp}}{\pgfpoint{19.064604bp}{128.344594bp}}{\pgfpoint{4.343639bp}{143.814082bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{1.0,1.0,1.0}\pgfseteorule\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4.343639bp}{143.814082bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{25.92607bp}{73.0786bp}}{\pgfpoint{7.462488bp}{43.387163bp}}{\pgfpoint{2.846592bp}{23.301779bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{15.44674bp}{3.216395bp}}{\pgfpoint{48.631287bp}{-3.146055bp}}{\pgfpoint{42.144082bp}{12.448187bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{39.898511bp}{59.729929bp}}{\pgfpoint{31.914259bp}{104.391838bp}}{\pgfpoint{41.76982bp}{128.469348bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{35.532123bp}{127.097055bp}}{\pgfpoint{19.064604bp}{128.344594bp}}{\pgfpoint{4.343639bp}{143.814082bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{20.156201bp}{144.469041bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{22.744845bp}{140.071464bp}}{\pgfpoint{21.372552bp}{136.4536bp}}{\pgfpoint{20.343332bp}{132.679793bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{27.17361bp}{129.280249bp}}{\pgfpoint{31.446432bp}{128.812421bp}}{\pgfpoint{33.255364bp}{128.84361bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{32.10139bp}{132.461474bp}}{\pgfpoint{32.475652bp}{134.675856bp}}{\pgfpoint{32.787537bp}{137.264501bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{30.198893bp}{138.075401bp}}{\pgfpoint{25.489431bp}{139.073433bp}}{\pgfpoint{20.156201bp}{144.469041bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{1.0,1.0,1.0}\pgfseteorule\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{20.156201bp}{144.469041bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{22.744845bp}{140.071464bp}}{\pgfpoint{21.372552bp}{136.4536bp}}{\pgfpoint{20.343332bp}{132.679793bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{27.17361bp}{129.280249bp}}{\pgfpoint{31.446432bp}{128.812421bp}}{\pgfpoint{33.255364bp}{128.84361bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{32.10139bp}{132.461474bp}}{\pgfpoint{32.475652bp}{134.675856bp}}{\pgfpoint{32.787537bp}{137.264501bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{30.198893bp}{138.075401bp}}{\pgfpoint{25.489431bp}{139.073433bp}}{\pgfpoint{20.156201bp}{144.469041bp}}
\pgfclosepath
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{416.499459bp}{161.030126bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{418.994537bp}{145.934899bp}}{\pgfpoint{391.829368bp}{77.694496bp}}{\pgfpoint{420.148511bp}{40.892084bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{366.25481bp}{165.147006bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{370.621198bp}{159.034063bp}}{\pgfpoint{372.367753bp}{151.424073bp}}{\pgfpoint{368.126119bp}{145.685391bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{387.026341bp}{167.673273bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{389.864493bp}{163.805901bp}}{\pgfpoint{389.802116bp}{159.751398bp}}{\pgfpoint{387.961995bp}{156.164722bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
\pgfsetrectcap 
\pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{399.714409bp}{150.471577bp}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{396.876257bp}{154.338949bp}}{\pgfpoint{398.997074bp}{157.364232bp}}{\pgfpoint{400.837194bp}{160.950908bp}}
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgftransformcm{1.0}{0.0}{0.0}{1.0}{\pgfpoint{148.434436bp}{90.668905bp}}
\pgftext[left,base]{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape\normalsize
\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}$E = m c^2$}
\end{pgfscope}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the output from jpgfdraw]

**Eventually realize that what I ask is far more complex than I imagined**

I realize why some of you ( gurus in TeX-TikZ) maybe you haven't responded to my question. Without much comment in following figure...problems of overlap has begining.......

(The figure isn't through code, but with editing in Gimp)

[image]

...**addition 1** ...after the response of @PeterGrill

I show here some figures with a scale corresponding to both x-y, scale-x, scale-y (factor=2).

Here I have posted the jpgfdraw file which I use to experiment
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxaG1GVbo3S5ZkJDbmMwYlROTUk

[image]

**I think the red lines must somehow remain stable. And black points to make connections with curves that vary**

[image]

---

... **addition 2**

At the moment I am trying to create the red curves through TikZ as shown in  handmade figure but my skills in the TikZ does not help me.
(*I think maybe something good  will come out from this ...maybe not*) ...

I think the solution will not come out of one  single piece of code  but rather will be piece by piece...obviously you probably have some better ideas, I would really like to hear those, really I have stuck

Comment: You are using ConTeXt? It seems so from your question, but it is not clear at all...

Comment: @tohecz No, I use Latex and I compiling with xelatex

Comment: I think it's Papyrus 1 - 1 Karathan. You can scale down the papyrus and make the text optional. Would that be enough?

Comment: @percusse Yes this is true but I was thinking something like this  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75129/boxed-tikz-and-colored-equation-background but on papyrus

Answer (score 15):

Well, here is a start. I am not too happy about how I computed the scaling factors, but should get you started until someone comes up with a better solution:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand*{\XScale}{1.0}%
\newcommand*{\YScale}{1.0}%

\makeatletter
\let\OldPgfpoint\pgfpoint
\renewcommand{\pgfpoint}[2]{%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\XScale*#1}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\YScale*#2}%
}%
\makeatother

\newlength{\NormalHeight}
\newlength{\NormalWidth}

\settoheight{\NormalHeight}{$\mathstrut$}
\settowidth{\NormalWidth}{$E = mc^2$}
\newcommand*{\Papyrus}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\XScale}{0.20*\widthof{#1}/\NormalWidth}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\YScale}{0.20*\heightof{#1}/\NormalHeight}
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{0bp}{420.849709bp}{179.390961bp}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
    \pgfsetrectcap 
    \pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{32.278702bp}{137.07737bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{5.113533bp}{147.962151bp}}{\pgfpoint{26.937674bp}{155.673503bp}}{\pgfpoint{37.413107bp}{145.194173bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{45.642968bp}{139.580246bp}}{\pgfpoint{46.640999bp}{127.003489bp}}{\pgfpoint{34.337142bp}{127.252997bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{0.747145bp}{137.108558bp}}{\pgfpoint{-15.689186bp}{157.100377bp}}{\pgfpoint{34.150011bp}{161.778649bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{103.887462bp}{161.404387bp}}{\pgfpoint{428.247698bp}{121.857389bp}}{\pgfpoint{415.897059bp}{164.398482bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{404.575639bp}{186.604683bp}}{\pgfpoint{351.368085bp}{173.848593bp}}{\pgfpoint{370.704945bp}{159.720209bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{403.140969bp}{148.211659bp}}{\pgfpoint{410.71977bp}{167.236634bp}}{\pgfpoint{387.453161bp}{167.766838bp}}
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
    \pgfsetrectcap 
    \pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{37.892612bp}{39.289968bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{107.630063bp}{38.915706bp}}{\pgfpoint{431.990299bp}{-1.754077bp}}{\pgfpoint{419.63966bp}{40.787015bp}}
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
    \pgfsetrectcap 
    \pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4.343639bp}{143.814082bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{25.92607bp}{73.0786bp}}{\pgfpoint{7.462488bp}{43.387163bp}}{\pgfpoint{2.846592bp}{23.301779bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{15.44674bp}{3.216395bp}}{\pgfpoint{48.631287bp}{-3.146055bp}}{\pgfpoint{42.144082bp}{12.448187bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{39.898511bp}{59.729929bp}}{\pgfpoint{31.914259bp}{104.391838bp}}{\pgfpoint{41.76982bp}{128.469348bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{35.532123bp}{127.097055bp}}{\pgfpoint{19.064604bp}{128.344594bp}}{\pgfpoint{4.343639bp}{143.814082bp}}
    \pgfclosepath
    \color[rgb]{1.0,1.0,1.0}\pgfseteorule\pgfusepath{fill}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4.343639bp}{143.814082bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{25.92607bp}{73.0786bp}}{\pgfpoint{7.462488bp}{43.387163bp}}{\pgfpoint{2.846592bp}{23.301779bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{15.44674bp}{3.216395bp}}{\pgfpoint{48.631287bp}{-3.146055bp}}{\pgfpoint{42.144082bp}{12.448187bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{39.898511bp}{59.729929bp}}{\pgfpoint{31.914259bp}{104.391838bp}}{\pgfpoint{41.76982bp}{128.469348bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{35.532123bp}{127.097055bp}}{\pgfpoint{19.064604bp}{128.344594bp}}{\pgfpoint{4.343639bp}{143.814082bp}}
    \pgfclosepath
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
    \pgfsetrectcap 
    \pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{20.156201bp}{144.469041bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{22.744845bp}{140.071464bp}}{\pgfpoint{21.372552bp}{136.4536bp}}{\pgfpoint{20.343332bp}{132.679793bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{27.17361bp}{129.280249bp}}{\pgfpoint{31.446432bp}{128.812421bp}}{\pgfpoint{33.255364bp}{128.84361bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{32.10139bp}{132.461474bp}}{\pgfpoint{32.475652bp}{134.675856bp}}{\pgfpoint{32.787537bp}{137.264501bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{30.198893bp}{138.075401bp}}{\pgfpoint{25.489431bp}{139.073433bp}}{\pgfpoint{20.156201bp}{144.469041bp}}
    \pgfclosepath
    \color[rgb]{1.0,1.0,1.0}\pgfseteorule\pgfusepath{fill}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{20.156201bp}{144.469041bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{22.744845bp}{140.071464bp}}{\pgfpoint{21.372552bp}{136.4536bp}}{\pgfpoint{20.343332bp}{132.679793bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{27.17361bp}{129.280249bp}}{\pgfpoint{31.446432bp}{128.812421bp}}{\pgfpoint{33.255364bp}{128.84361bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{32.10139bp}{132.461474bp}}{\pgfpoint{32.475652bp}{134.675856bp}}{\pgfpoint{32.787537bp}{137.264501bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{30.198893bp}{138.075401bp}}{\pgfpoint{25.489431bp}{139.073433bp}}{\pgfpoint{20.156201bp}{144.469041bp}}
    \pgfclosepath
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
    \pgfsetrectcap 
    \pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{416.499459bp}{161.030126bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{418.994537bp}{145.934899bp}}{\pgfpoint{391.829368bp}{77.694496bp}}{\pgfpoint{420.148511bp}{40.892084bp}}
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
    \pgfsetrectcap 
    \pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{366.25481bp}{165.147006bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{370.621198bp}{159.034063bp}}{\pgfpoint{372.367753bp}{151.424073bp}}{\pgfpoint{368.126119bp}{145.685391bp}}
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
    \pgfsetrectcap 
    \pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{387.026341bp}{167.673273bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{389.864493bp}{163.805901bp}}{\pgfpoint{389.802116bp}{159.751398bp}}{\pgfpoint{387.961995bp}{156.164722bp}}
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1.0bp}
    \pgfsetrectcap 
    \pgfsetmiterjoin \pgfsetmiterlimit{10.0}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{399.714409bp}{150.471577bp}}
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{396.876257bp}{154.338949bp}}{\pgfpoint{398.997074bp}{157.364232bp}}{\pgfpoint{400.837194bp}{160.950908bp}}
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgftransformcm{1.0}{0.0}{0.0}{1.0}{\pgfpoint{148.434436bp}{90.668905bp}}
    \pgftext[left,base]{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape\normalsize
    \color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}#1}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \end{pgfpicture}%
}
    
\begin{document}
\Papyrus{$E' = mc +  m c^2 + m c^3$}
\Papyrus{$\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} = f(n)}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} = g(n)}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , ...the first problems began to appear. However you skipped ahead one step :-)

Comment: @karathan: Huh? Skipped ahead one step?

Comment: oh I used a wrong expression? .... my English not help me ... I apologize for this

Comment: @karathan: No problem. I thought that perhaps you saw a problem with this answer.

Comment: the only certainty is that I will write error and other expressions ... my fault and google's translator... :-) .....the set of commands that you gave I definitely could not do it ..... and though the dodge will allow me here to say "thank you" :-)

Comment: Curving the text along the surface of the papyrus would probably be too difficult, but I wonder if the papyrus and text could be shaded to give some semblance of that 3D effect?

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled over this thread in search of an old fashioned role of paper layout block that could dynamically wrap a paragraph. I didn't find anything, so I coded a simple one myself. For everyone getting here and also is interested in something like that, here is my quick solution:

```
% Papyrus paper style frame border
% Author: Fabian Ostermann (github.com/OysterSandwich)
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Define background layer
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\tikzset{
    % Add more line modifications here:
    papyrus line/.style={ line width=1pt }
}

%Usage: \drawRole{<anchor>}{<direction>}{<sizeFactor>}
\def\drawRole#1#2#3{%
    \begin{scope}[yscale=#2,scale=0.6*#3]
        % Draw role on the left
        \draw[papyrus line] (A.#1 west) .. controls +(0,1) and +(0,1) .. +(-1,0) .. controls +(0,-1) and +(0,-1) .. +(-.2,0) .. controls +(0,.7) and +(0,.7) .. +(-.8,0) .. controls +(0,-.5) and +(0,-.5) .. +(-.5,0) -- +(-.2,0);
        \draw[papyrus line] (A.#1 west) +(-.6,-.75) -- +(0,-.75);
        \draw[papyrus line] (A.#1 west) +(-.65,-.375) -- +(-.25,-.375);
        
        
        % Draw right corner and vertical line
        \draw[papyrus line] (A.#1 east) .. controls +(0,.7) and +(.4,0) .. +(-.5,0.751) -- ($(A.#1 west)+(-.5,.751)$);
    \end{scope}
}

%Usage: \papyrus[<scale of decoration>]{<content>}
\newcommand\papyrus[2][1]{%
        \tikz{
            \node[inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=0.5em] (A) {#2};  % Draw the text of the node
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  % Draw the shape behind
                
                \drawRole{north}{1}{#1}
                \drawRole{south}{-1}{#1}
                
                %\draw ([papyrus line] A.north west) -- (A.north east);
                \draw[papyrus line] (A.north east) -- (A.south east);
                %\draw[papyrus line] (A.south east) -- (A.south west);
                \draw[papyrus line] (A.south west) -- (A.north west);
                %\fill[white]   (A.north west) -- (A.north east) -- (A.south east) -- (A.south west) -- (A.north west);
        \end{pgfonlayer}}

}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \papyrus{
            \parbox{.9\textwidth}{\lipsum[8]}
        }
        \papyrus{
            \parbox{.6\textwidth}{\lipsum[5]}
        }
        \papyrus[.6]{
            Short text
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Also, my thanks to Jose Luis Diaz for the [Torn Paper example](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/torn-paper/) which made a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

1. 1- open inkscape program.

   2- draw your design + your formula.

   3- export as tex.

   4- include tex file in the main document.

regards

Comment: you can instead code your presentation in assembler language. That would have equal convenience for a moderate length document