# How can we use tikz package to draw a rectangle and fill it with a color for the equations?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can we use tikz package to draw a rectangle and fill it with a color  for the equations?
like the following

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
f(x)=ax+b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please have alook here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75129/boxed-tikz-and-colored-equation-background

Comment: Take a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20575/attractive-boxed-equations/288326#288326

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}
\hfsetfillcolor{blue!10}
\hfsetbordercolor{blue}
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq2}
\tikzmarkin{b}  f(x)=ax+b\tikzmarkend{b}\\
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**for white borders**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}
\hfsetfillcolor{blue!20}
\hfsetbordercolor{white}
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq2}
\tikzmarkin{b}  f(x)=ax+b\tikzmarkend{b}\\
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use tcolorbox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!10,text width=5cm]
\begin{equation}
\centering  f(x)=ax+b
\end{equation}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with `\tcbset{colframe=white}`:

[image]

in tikz(but tcolorobx i think is the better one):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [fill=cyan!20,text width=4cm] at (0,0) {\begin{equation}f(x)=ax+b\end{equation}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: How can we do it without frame?

Comment: How can we do it with \usepackage{tikz}? because I'd like to use its color.

Comment: without frame use `\tcbset{colframe=white}`

Comment: you can also use : `\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=blue!10,text width=5cm,
      frame hidden]`  with `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` in the prehambule

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: How can we make the number of equation outside ?

Comment: You can use `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` in order to remove the numbering, but you needto load `\usepackage{amsmath}.`