# Align and boxed don't work together

Tags: align, miktex

When I try to input:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
w(t) &=& \frac{1}{2}Cv^2(t)\\
\boxed{w(t) &=& \frac{1}{2}C \frac{q(t)^2}{C^2}}\\
w(t) &=& \frac{1}{2}\frac{q(t)^2}{C}\\
w(t) &=& \frac{1}{2}Cv^2(t)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

I get an error. The following code works but the box is way of to the left... (I didn't use `&=&` on the boxed equation this time.)

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
w(t) &=& \frac{1}{2}Cv^2(t)\\
\boxed{w(t) = \frac{1}{2}C \frac{q(t)^2}{C^2}}\\
w(t) &=& \frac{1}{2}\frac{q(t)^2}{C}\\
w(t) &=& \frac{1}{2}Cv^2(t)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Are there any ways to fix this issue?

Comment: Avoid `eqnarray`; see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Comment: A very much related is my very _first_ question on TeX.SE: [Highlight an equation within an align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13681/highlight-an-equation-within-an-align-environment). Also see [Highlight an equation within an align environment with color option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/highlight-an-equation-within-an-align-environment-with-color-option/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why no use `\Aboxed` command of the package `mathtools`? inside of an `align*` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
w(t) &= \frac{1}{2}Cv^2(t)\\
\Aboxed{w(t) &= \frac{1}{2}C \frac{q(t)^2}{C^2}}\\
w(t) &= \frac{1}{2}\frac{q(t)^2}{C}\\
w(t) &= \frac{1}{2}Cv^2(t)\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My editor doesnt want to import mathtools for some reason...

Comment: What system do you use? OS? Tex distribution? Editor?

Comment: Win8, texmaker and the error I get is: 'mathtools.sly' not found

Comment: MiKTeX or TeXLive?

Comment: You must install the `mathtools` package. If you use *MiKTeX* install from *MiKTeX Package Manager*.

Comment: Ok will try that. Is the software called MiKTeX Package Manager or is it a option somwhere in a website or the texmaker. Sorry for being slow on this :,(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17839/discussion-between-skpblack-and-rectifier).