# hiding equation with fcolorbox won't work

Tags: color, align

I'm learning some formulas and in order to hide them (=print white) within my pdf-document using fcolorbox. I tried to create some macro, here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} \nonstopmode
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\f[2]{
%    \text{#1: } & #2 \\ % works fine
    \text{#1: } & \fcolorbox{white}{white}{#2} \\ % won't work
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \f{Pythagoras}{a^2 + b^2 &=& c^2}
        \f{Plank Equation}{E &=& \hbar\,\omega}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You can see I indicated two lines with comments. Why does the first line produce the expected output, but the second one yields errors? Namely: Missing $ inserted.

Is there a better command to colorize/hide equations? I tried `\phantom{}` which works fine but only without ampersands…

Comment: `\fcolorbox` saves the contents in an extra box and so the ampersand is handled as a special token which has to escaped.

Comment: removing the ampersands did not help

Comment: You have to change "#2" into "$#2$" or "\ensuremath{#2}" in the defintion of the macro `\f` and "&=&" into " = "  on two places, where you use this macro. Then your document compiles. But the equation is not hidden. It is simply printed on white background in a rectangle with white boundary. To hide some content, try `ocg-p` package.

Comment: If you don't use ampersands, `\newcommand\f[2]{\text{#1: } & \color{white}#2 \\}` works as well.

Comment: thank you for your hints, but I'd prefer to keep the ampersands, as the documents contains many equations and I want to switch them "on" and "off" on purpose

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13681/highlight-an-equation-within-an-align-environment/13693#13693 is perhaps of interest.

Comment: Did you think about using the `ifthen` package?  `\ifthenelse{show_equations}{$e=mc^2$}{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ifthen` instead of fiddling with the colour.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newboolean{showeq}
\setboolean{showeq}{true}  % <-- comment this out to hide the equations
\begin{align*}
    \text{Pythagoras:}     && \ifthenelse{\boolean{showeq}}{a^2+b^2 &=c^2}{} \\
    \text{Plank equation:} && \ifthenelse{\boolean{showeq}}{E &= \hbar\,\omega}{}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with your code for `\f`:

1. `\fcolorbox` stores its contents in a box, which switches the mode back to text (from math). As elements like `a^2` can only be used in math mode, this causes the error (missing `$` inserted). If you're using `\fcolorbox`, you need to switch back to math mode explicitly: `\fcolorbox{.}{.}{$..$}`.
2. Since `\fcolorbox` boxes its contents, it has no reference on using the symbol `&`/its hidden from its intended meaning - typically used for alignment inside `tabular` or `align` (and friends). So, just drop it in this case.

While using single-character macros may be convenient, it's advised to use something a little more describing (also because some core macros could be single-characters themselves). Here's a revised version of your input:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newif\ifshoweq\showeqtrue
\newcommand{\showeq}[2]{%
  \text{#1: } & \ifshoweq #2\else\phantom{#2}\fi
}
\begin{document}
Equations are visible:
\begin{align*}
  \showeq{Pythagoras}{a^2 + b^2 = c^2} \\
  \showeq{Plank Equation}{E = \hbar\,\omega}
\end{align*}

\showeqfalse

Equations are invisible:
\begin{align*}
  \showeq{Pythagoras}{a^2 + b^2 = c^2} \\
  \showeq{Plank Equation}{E = \hbar\,\omega}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

`\showeq{<name>}{<eqn>}` prints `<name>` in text mode, right aligned, and left aligns `<eqn>`. If the boolean variable `\ifshoweq` is set to `\showeqfalse` (default is to show equations/`\showeqtrue`), then it sets the equation as a `\phantom`. This provides the correct spacing of the equation, without actually printing it (also, no need for using "white" as a colour).

Comment: thank you for your helpful and explaining answer! Unfortunately I can only accept one answer, and I accepted already one :-(