# How to define a math mode macro like mathtools' \Aboxed but colored for multiline equations in an align/align* environment without breaking alignment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, color, align, boxes

Before I get to the question and to not receive the answers I do not want, I want to point out that I mainly have 4 usage of equation or math-related boxes in LaTeX (For the question related to the title, skip to usage number **4**).

#### 1. For boxing a big list of mathematical properties, in which I use my own custom `tcolorbox` environment defined using [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)'s `\newtcolorbox` macro.

Example:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[preview,border={5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm},varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{colback=black!5!white,colframe=black,boxrule=1pt,arc=0mm,#1}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\small%
\begin{mybox}[before skip=4ex, after skip=5ex, boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=15pt,top=-7pt,bottom=10pt]
\begin{alignat*}{99}
    &\text{(Associative law for addition)} & && a + (b + c) & &&= (a + b) + c. \tag{P1}  \\
    &\text{(Existence of an additive identity)} & && a + 0 & &&= 0 + a = a. \tag{P2}  \\
    &\text{(Existence of additive inverses)} & && a + (-a) & &&= (-a) + a = 0. \tag{P3} \\
    &\text{(Commutative law for addition)} && & a + b & &&= b + a. \tag{P4} \\
    &\text{(Associative law for multiplication)} & && a \cdot (b \cdot c) & &&= (a \cdot b) \cdot c. \tag{P5} \\
    &\text{(Existence of a multiplicative identity)} & && a \cdot 1 & &&= 1 \cdot a = a;\quad 1 \neq 0. \tag{P6}\\
    &\text{(Existence of multplicative inverses)} & && a \cdot a^{-1} & &&= a^{-1} \cdot a = 1, \text{ for } a \neq 0. \tag{P7} \\
    &\text{(Commutative law for multiplication)} & && a \cdot b & &&= b \cdot a. \tag{P8} \\
    &\text{(Distributive law)} & && a \cdot (b + c) & &&= a \cdot b + a \cdot c. \tag{P9}
\end{alignat*}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image: Usage 1]

#### 2. For highlighting a standalone multiline mathematical definition or equation, in which I use [`empheq`](https://ctan.org/pkg/empheq)'s `empheq` + `align`/`align*` environment + [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)'s `\tchbhighmath` box (a special case of the `\tcboxmath` macro).

Example:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[preview,border={5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm},varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\tcbset{highlight math style={colback=black!5!white,colframe=black,boxrule=1pt,capture=hbox,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,left=4pt,right=4pt}}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\small%
The fact that \(-a > 0\) if \(a < 0\) is the basis of a concept which will play an extremely important role in this book. For any number \(a\), we define the \textbf{absolute value} \(\abs{a}\) of \(a\) as follows:

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align*}
    \abs{a} &=
    \begin{cases*}
        \phantom{-}a, & if \(a\geq 0\), \\
        -a, & if \(a\leq 0\).
    \end{cases*}
    \\[3pt]
    \abs{a} &= \sqrt{a^2}.
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image: Usage 2]

#### 3. For highlighting the end result of a mathematical solutions in an `align`/`align*` environment, in which I use a custom colored version macro of [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)' `\Aboxed` macro taken and modified from this [TeX.SX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610299/228055)

(I switched the optional argument to be the background color instead of the frame color)

Example:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[preview,border={-15mm 5mm 10mm 0mm},varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{xcolor}

    % \Acolorboxed (color \Aboxed command) modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610299/228055
    % Basic syntax: \Acolorboxed[<background color>]{<LHS> &<aligned character> <RHS>}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Acolorboxed[2][yellow!75]{%
   \let\bgroup{\romannumeral-`}%
   \@Acolorboxed{#1}#2&&\ENDDNE
}
\def\@Acolorboxed#1#2&#3&#4\ENDDNE{%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\displaystyle#2{}\m@th$\kern\fboxsep \kern\fboxrule}%
  \edef\@tempa{\kern\wd\z@ & \kern-\the\wd\z@ \fboxsep\the\fboxsep \fboxrule\the\fboxrule}%
  \@tempa
  \fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\m@th$\displaystyle#2#3$}%
} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\small%

\begin{align*}
            x^3 + x^2 - 4x + 2 &= (x - 1)(x^2 + 2x - 2) = 0, \\
            x_1 &= 1, \\ 
            x_2 &= \frac{-2 + \sqrt{2^2 - 4(1)(-2)}}{2(1)} = \frac{2 + 2\sqrt{3}}{2},  \\ 
            x_3 &= \frac{-2 - \sqrt{2^2 - 4(1)(-2)}}{2(1)} = \frac{2 - 2\sqrt{3}}{2}, \\[1.5ex]
            \Acolorboxed{x &\in \left\{1 - \sqrt{3}, 1, 1 + \sqrt{3}\right\}.}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Usage 3]

#### 4. For highlighting with color the *multiline* end result of a mathematical solutions in an `align`/`align*` environment without breaking the alignment from the previous unboxed lines, in which I don't know what to use.

I want a mixture of usage number **3** and usage number **4** but using `empheq` would not continue the alignment from the previous unboxed lines, and using `\Acolorboxed` (similar to `\Aboxed`) would not be possible since the macro cannot handle multiline aligned equations. So I need a new macro.

An example of this macro, let's call it `\Acolorboxedmulti[<background color>]{<LHS> &<alignment character> <RHS>}`, would be:

```
\begin{align*}
    a &= 1, \\
    b &= 2, \\
    \Acolorboxedmulti[yellow!75]{%
    c &= 3, \\
    d &= 4, \\
    e &= 5.
    }
\end{align*}
```

Essentially, my question is

### How can I define a macro like [`\Acolorboxed`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610299/228055) but can handle multiline aligned equations in one box fitted to the width without breaking the alignment from previous lines in `align`/`align*`?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [beamer - How to put box around a single equation in align environment? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315117/how-to-put-box-around-a-single-equation-in-align-environment) though. Although I don't claim to fully understand the question.

Comment: Or [Highlight an equation within an align environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13681/highlight-an-equation-within-an-align-environment/13693#13693). (I can't tell if *those 2* are duplicate of each other either.)

Comment: @user202729 Those answers are not what I'm trying to achieve {a multiline equation consisting of aligned equations all inside a box fitted to width with an optional argument for the background color while preserving the alignment with previous unboxed lines in `align`/`align*`.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you look for. Is it so that in your third example, you would like to put a box around the three rows starting with `x_1`, `x_2` and `x_3`, for example? (Unrelated, the last row there is mathematically wrong. `x` is _not_ equal to the set.)

Comment: @mickep No, the third usage is already fine as is.  I'm looking for a way to write the ***fourth***  usage (see the desired example at the end). (Oops, I should've written `x \in \left\{1 - \sqrt{3}, 1, 1 + \sqrt{3}\right\}.` instead, my bad. I'll fix it soon.)

Comment: Yes, but another example of the fourth one would be what I describe, right? That is, you want to frame several lines in an align.(?)

Comment: @mickep Yes, but without breaking the alignment of the lines before the multiline boxed equations (so all of it is in a single `align`/`align*` environment).

Comment: [math mode - How to box two lines inside align* - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30250/how-to-box-two-lines-inside-align)?

Comment: You could also use \tikzmark on two corners.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/how-to-highlight-text-formulas-with-tikz