# & Delimiter within other Functions

Tags: align

When using any environments that use a `&` as the delimiter (align, tabular, array etc. ), it is not possible to delimit from within another function, eg.

```
\begin{align}
   \boxed{this & that} \\
   \boxed{& and this aswell}
\end{align}
```

Some commands, like `\text` allows you to break such that it isn't an issue, but if I wanted to have a `\boxed{}` environment stretching over these delimiters, the environment ceases to register them.

Is there a way to correctly delimit within a command (in a simple manner)? Or is it best to find a different way to display the data?

Comment: I was a wee bit confused by your denoting `&` as delimiter (which in TeX is something else) but I think you just want the macro `\Aboxed` from the `mathtools` package (an extension to `amsmath`). Though I don't understand what you mean by saying the `\text` allows you to do that (it shouldn't, at least not if you use it in the same way.)

Comment: `\boxed` does not allow `&` separators inside its argument, so I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13681/82917

Comment: With text{} you can write `\text{this} & \text{that}` and it looks no different to  `\text{this that}`. That is not the case with `\boxed`. 

The `\Aboxed{}` method look like it will work though, thanks