# Highlight or underline answer in Latex when code is in begin/end{align*}

Tags: align, underline, syntax-highlighting

I normally write my solutions to mathematics problems in Latex using the begin/end{align*} feature.

How does one highlight an equation, or answer in my case, when the code is in begin/end{align*} ?

See my code below:

```
\begin{align*}
    %--
    i^7 &= 1 \times i^3 \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &=  i^3 \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &= i^2 \times i \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &= -1 \times i \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &=  -i \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &=  -i
\end{align*}
```

So I would like to highlight the last line BUT maintain the alignment

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean underline as the highlight as said in the title? (Well, it is easy to change its color just using `\color{}` within a `{}`.)

Comment: Will `\color{}` maintain the alignment so that all the equal signs are under each other?

Comment: Here the last line you can use `\color{red} i^7 & \color{red}=-i` and it looks right. (No `{}` needed in `align` environment.)

Comment: I tried your code and it gives me red text.  I just want to highlight the the answer `i^7 =  -i`.

Comment: SOmething like this works fine for me. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools} % or \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    %--
    i^7 &= 1 \times i^3 \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &=  i^3 \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &= i^2 \times i \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &= -1 \times i \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &=  -i \\[5mm]
    %--
    \color{red} i^7 & \color{red}  =-i
\end{align*}
\end{document}
` Result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdSD9.png)

Comment: I think your code changes the colour of the text.  I would like to highlight the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135801/discussion-between-teddy-van-jerry-and-stephan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be concluded as **colorbox inside align**, so we can use

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13693/234654
\newlength\dlf
\newcommand\alignedbox[2]{
  % #1 = before alignment
  % #2 = after alignment
  &
  \begingroup
  \settowidth\dlf{$\displaystyle #1$}
  \addtolength\dlf{\fboxsep+\fboxrule}
  \hspace{-\dlf}
  \fcolorbox{yellow}{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1 #2$}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    %--
    i^7 &= 1 \times i^3 \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &=  i^3 \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &= i^2 \times i \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &= -1 \times i \\[5mm]
    %--
    i^7 &=  -i \\[5mm]
    %--
     \alignedbox{i^7}{=-i}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This genius idea is borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13693/234654).

This method calculates the length before the aligned mark `&` into variable `\dlf`. Then `\hspace` is used to left shift the colorbox. Now the alignment is achieved.

[image: RESULT]